# How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript

Tags: javascript, href, attr

How to change the `href` attribute value of an `<a/>` tag through Javascript on button click ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function f1()
  {
    document.getElementById("abc").href="xyz.php"; 
  }
</script>

<a href="" id="abc">jhg</a>
<a href="" id="" onclick="f1()">jhhghj</a>
```

Comment: The Way of Accessibility dictates to not use links this manner. Here: http://xkr.us/js/links

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Without having a `href`, the click will reload the current page, so you need something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="f1()">jhhghj</a>
```

Or prevent the scroll like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="f1(); return false;">jhhghj</a>
```

Or `return false` in your `f1` function and:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return f1();">jhhghj</a>
```

....or, the unobtrusive way:

```
<a href="#" id="abc">jhg</a>
<a href="#" id="myLink">jhhghj</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("abc").href="xyz.php"; 
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: suggest add `event && event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();` before `return false`

Answer (score 55):

Exactly what Nick Carver did there but I think it would be best if used the DOM setAttribute method.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function() {
        var link = document.getElementById("abc");
        link.setAttribute("href", "xyz.php");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

It's one extra line of code but find it better structure-wise.

Comment: IMO there's no need here, this has been a DOM property forever, `.href` works in all browsers...for example would you use `.getAttribute("id")` instead of just `.id`? :)

Comment: You're right, it doesn't do anything special or different, it's just structural-wise. I like having all my DOM functions this way for later debugging/review: It's easier for me to see what the function is doing with this methods. Obviously your answer is right on the money :)

Comment: Thank you! still works today!

Answer (score 7):

remove `href` attribute:

```
<a id="" onclick="f1()">jhhghj</a>
```

if link styles are important then:

```
<a href="javascript:void(f1())">jhhghj</a>
```

Comment: a `<a>` tag without `href` attribute? what? why?

Comment: Leaving out the href will change it's style and behaviour. It then acts as an anchor instead of a link.

Comment: no href makes it an anchor, click converts to a link, pretty normal

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on it. I needed to create a URL by collecting the value from a text box , when the user presses a Submit button.

```html
<html>
<body>

Hi everyone

<p id="result"></p>

<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="2"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
 document.getElementById("abc").href="http://arindam31.pythonanywhere.com/hello/" + result;
}  
</script>


<a href="#" id="abc">abc</a>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" id="a" onclick="ChangeHref()">1.Change 2.Go</a>

<script>
function ChangeHref(){
document.getElementById("a").setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='http://religiasatanista.ro'");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function f1(mHref)
  {
    document.getElementById("abc").href=mHref; 
  }
</script>

<a href="" id="abc">jhg</a>
<button onclick="f1("dynamicHref")">Change HREF</button>

Just give the dynamic HREF in Paramters
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a link dynamically change on clicking it:

```
<input type="text" id="emailOfBookCustomer" style="direction:RTL;"></input>
        <a 
         onclick="this.href='<%= request.getContextPath() %>/Jahanpay/forwardTo.jsp?handle=<%= handle %>&Email=' + document.getElementById('emailOfBookCustomer').value;" href=''>
    A dynamic link 
            </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know its bit old post. Still, it might help some one.

Instead of  tag,if possible you can this as well.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function IsItWorking() {
          // Do your stuff here ...
            alert("YES, It Works...!!!");
        }
    </script>   

    `<asp:HyperLinkID="Link1"NavigateUrl="javascript:IsItWorking();"`            `runat="server">IsItWorking?</asp:HyperLink>`
```

Any comments on this?