# Changing the href of an html tag with css

Tags: html, css, href

I need to change this A tag from

```
<a href="contact.html" >Contact</a>
```

to

```
<a href="tel:+13174562564" >Contact</a>
```

with only Css if it's possible or like this

```
<a href="tel:+13174562564" >+13174562564</a>
```

i have a lot of pages and i don't want to edit all of them it will take a life time that's why i need to do it in CSS and i have no JS linked to them

Answer (score 36):

CSS is display only, you cannot modify the document object model with it.  Sorry, this cannot be done.  I wish I had a better answer, but 'it cannot be done' is the only answer.

Answer (score 12):

CSS is for **presentation** and cannot be used to modify the HTML markup in the way you intend.
You need JavaScript for this.

It should be a **[fairly short script.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365272/759019)**

Answer (score 12):

one solution is to hide a tag and put another

```
<div id="tag1">
<a href="#tag1">link1</a>
<a href="#tag2">link2</a>
</div>
```

css :

```
a[href="#tag1"] {
display:block;
}

a[href="#tag2"] {
display:none;
}

#tag1:target  a[href="#tag1"]{
 display:none;
}

#tag1:target  a[href="#tag2"]{
 display:block;
}
```

I use this method for responsive "buttons" of my menu bar