# How to hide a parent element on click of a child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I make parent div element hidden, on click of anchor tag within the div element.

I know how can we do this in javascript/jQuery. I am looking for pure CSS solution

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <a>helo</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>hi</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you look for is not exactly possible in CSS, and your best bet is some hacks - one of them is using a `checkbox` and `label`.

See demo below:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#checkbox,
#checkbox:checked + div {
  display: none;
}
a {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<div>
  <span>
    <a><label for="checkbox">hello</label></a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a><label for="checkbox">hi</label></a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats very creative/innovative!!

Comment: What if its an element other than `label` ?

Comment: Thanks kukkuz for the solution ,though a hack worked out well for me ...i was looking to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647221/how-to-make-a-toggleable-navbar-in-pure-css/40648227?noredirect=1#comment68549678_40648227,then stuck with the problem i gave here of how to hide and show using pure css but could not achieve this problem i linked

Comment: @Srisa At first look I jumped into that it would work in  [this question as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40647221/how-to-make-a-toggleable-navbar-in-pure-css), but it will not as then the `a` tags will stop working...

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want. But still this would make it visible once mouse button is UP.

There is only one thing you can do, Make it transparent, But it still will be there, And you cannot achieve this perfectly without JS:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px
}
div {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity:1;
  animation: hide 0.1s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
div a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
div:active {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes hide {
1%{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    position:absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <a>helo</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>hi</a>
  </span>
</div>
Some randow text/element
```

Comment: This looks good...but i dont want it to get it up on mouse event

Comment: I have edited it, But no way you are getting this without JS

Answer (score 0):

you can use :active,:focus pseudo class.

it's simple solution.you should use both class

```
span:active div.parent{background:#eaeaea}
span:focus div.parent{background:#eaeaea}
```

i put the snippet in.

thank you

Comment: Well, it doesnt seem simple styling a parent element on child element click, Did you rad what OP wants?

Comment: can you add a snippet it would help me ...i could not get a solution

Comment: Jones Vinoth Joseph : what r u talking about