# add href to a link via CSS

Tags: css, href

Tell me how to add href to a link via CSS. How to do it in the standard way is clear.

```
<div>
<a href="example.com">Button</a>
</div>
```

But I need pure HTML. And in CSS, specify which address to make the transition to.

```
<div>
<a class="button-click"></a>
</div>


.button-click a {href:"https://example.com"}
```

How do I specify a path in CSS?

Comment: you can't use CSS here but with js or jq you can handle it perfectly!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the href of an html tag with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356717/changing-the-href-of-an-html-tag-with-css)

Answer (score 2):

CSS cannot be used to perform action or make changes to DOM. Its used for presentation purpose.
You can use script to do the manipulation not css.

Comment: Clear. Very sorry.
Tell me, what script should I write?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript/4365272#4365272

Comment: I apologize in advance for my ignorance in the code))The option that you offered me-I think it suits me. But I can't understand why there are two links? And each one has its own ID. Could you show me how to do this with my example? Thank you in advance.