# svg or javascript to replace url part of use

Tags: javascript, css, svg, blazor-server-side

I have some:

```
<svg class="image image-size-09em" role="img" area-hidden="true">
  <use href="_content/blazor/blazor.svg#chevron-right"></use>
</svg>
```

I want to replace **chevron-right** with **chevron-left** for all svgs in the page. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to select all the relevant elements, then change all of their `hrefs`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("use").forEach(element=>{
  element.href.baseVal = element.href.baseVal.replace("chevron-right", "chevron-left")
})
```

```html
<svg class="image image-size-09em" role="img" area-hidden="true">
  <use href="_content/blazor/blazor.svg#chevron-right"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks , Is there a way to do the same with css?

Comment: No, CSS is display-only, like this answer says https://stackoverflow.com/a/15356777/16634738