# Adding javascript incremented filenames into html a tag

Tags: javascript, html, printing, href, increment

I have a list of pictures that need to be displayed. The list of pictures is very large (500+) and I did not want to load each by individually naming them in the html code for the href attribute of the a tag. Hence, I used javascript to generate filenames incremented by 1, which produces the correct filepath. 
Here is the javascript:

```
function bigpicture()
    {
        var filepath = "\"images/print/latest/" ;
        var ext = ".png\"";
        var total = filepath + num + ext;
        document.write(total)
        num = num + 1;
    }
```

When I call bigpicture() I get the correct filepath and name, and all multiple calls it increments as well. My problem is getting this string to display after the href attribute of my a tag, as seen here:

HTML

```
<div class = "big">
        <ul>    
            <li>
                <a href=<script>bigpicture()</script> rel="lightbox" title=""><img class="floated_img" img src="images/print/latest/small/1.png" /></a>
            </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

I assumed (incorrectly) that I could call the function like this, but it does not work. Could anyone tell me how to execute the script in a way that the sting appears after href? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should add the **href** dynamically either using **onCLick** or inside **bigpicture()** function during the filename generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your doing it won't work because the function call is not bound to any
event in your html code like an onload or onsubmit and therefore won't execute.

I would use jQuery to append to your `ul` in the `big` div.
Your call to `bigpicture()` could look like this:

```
<script>

  function bigpicture()
  {
    var filepath = "./images/print/latest/" ;
    var ext = ".png\"";
    for(var i = 0; i < numOfPictures; i++){
        $('#big ul').append('<li>' + filepath + i + ext + '</li>');
      }

  }

  $(function(){     //this is jQuery shorthand for document ready
      bigpicture(); //anything in this anonymous function will execute
    })              //after HTML document has been loaded

</script>
```

The document ready info comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: That seems way better, how would I implement it in my html though? should I just call the function in the list where my list object would usually be?

Comment: The function, when executed, would populate the `ul` with `li`'s.The function is being called once already in the document.ready anonymous function. The only thing you would need to add to the code above is the true value of `numOfPictures`

Answer (score 1):

You could place your function within an `onclick` handler.

The `onclick` handler will bind the variable `this` to your a-node.

Maybe you need in combination with lightbox a handler before `onclick` like `onmousedown`

[How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)