# anchor/href change dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I make a dynamic anchor?

I have this table in my database;

```
----------------------------------------------
:    **id**    :    **Names**                :
----------------------------------------------
:     1        : Name1, Name2, Name3         :
----------------------------------------------
```

I return it to my page and what I want to do is when I click in one of the name I want to change the link id.

For example when I clicked Name1 my anchor should be

```
<a href="http://name.com?id=name1">
```

and when I click Name2

```
<a href="http://name.com?id=name2">
```

and so on.

How can I possibly do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the second Name2 should be <a href="http://name.com?id=name2">

Comment: You want to change each anchor on the server side, before the page is displayed?

Comment: Do you have different names in same column? separated with `,` ?

Comment: please define what you expect from a dynamic anchor, it is not clear at this point what exactly your expecting.

Comment: Yes Sergio. Kgarrigan, I want it to change on the page.

Comment: DevZero, I have diff name in the same column. So when I display the other column I want to also create an anchor for it.

Comment: It is usually inefficient to store multiple values in the same row, in the same column. Can you show how you are retrieving the names from your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    Foreach ($name as $n){
        echo '<a href ="http://name.com?id='.$n.'">'.$n.' </a>';
?>
```

Guessing this is what you are looking for. Question is a little vague. Could use more information.

Comment: Honestly, make your code clear: array is a massive of data, so write properly `$names as $name`, it is so simple.

Comment: Honestly, since $n is local to the foreach loop, I think it really comes down to a matter of style preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can script code to the HTML page which does this change without reloading the page. This modifies the HTML document at runtime, for example see here: [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

The object you click on now needs to have an onclick handler like in the example.