# How to create elements in javascript with href=variable?

Tags: javascript, createelement

how to create elements in javascript with href=variable?
how to create this with javascript when you click a button?
every time you hit the button, another div will appear.

```
<div><a href=myfirstvariable><img src="mysecondvariable"></a></div>
```

thanks

Comment: What outcome/output do you want? A new `div` to appear (where?) in the page on every click of the `a` element? Or...something else entirely?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript

Comment: You are asking too many things at once and it is not clear what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you want, but you can create an `a` element with `href=variable` like this :

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://google.fr";
```

Comment: Thank you! just what i been looking for