# hide URL in status for all hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I inserted a PrettyPhoto gallery.

```
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="prettyPhoto[01]" onClick="href='image01.jpg'">
                <img src="image01.jpg" width="200px" />
            </a>
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="prettyPhoto[01]" onClick="href='image02.jpg'">
                <img src="image02.jpg" width="200px" />
            </a>
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' rel="prettyPhoto[01]" onClick="href='image03.jpg'">
                <img src="image03.jpg" width="200px" />
            </a>
```

I used onClick event to hide URL in status bar. But, when I try to visualize the photo gallery I view only clicked image.

How it's possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: " But, when I try to visualize the photo gallery I view only clicked image." What does this means?

Comment: using rel='prettyphoto[01]' I create a image gallery (slideshow) for this 3 images. When I click on one of these 3 images I must view a slideshow for all 3 images. But I view only clicked image, the others 2 image are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting the href like this will work, try `location.href` instead

Comment: using location.href it's open clicked image in

Comment: So you will have to do something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4365272/20126

Comment: did you use prettyphoto? to have an idea how it work.