# Add URL to href tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I add a Url to the href tag with javascript? Can you help, please?

```
<a id="url-link" href="" onclick="" title="" class="btn">CLICK</a>
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jL7Lcqqa/1/)

Comment: What did you try so far? if you searched for set attribute value javascript, you will get what you need exactly.

Comment: I am guessing you didn't search for an answer before asking. many examples available:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = document.getElementById('url-link');
a.href="your link here";
```

Comment: Its good to answer questions. But when questions are trivial, it is good to "ask" or "guide" OP to discovering the answer themselves.

Comment: Thank you, Veniamin. Works great!