# how to send values through request without using form in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, web-applications

I am working on online shopping website like flipkart and want to forward values through request or say just want to append value to URL, But I have not used form so, I can not use form action. For instance consider following situation.

```
value1<input type="number" min="1" name="value1">
         <a href="somePage.jsp">value1</a>

          value2<input type="number" min="1" name="value2">
         <a href="somePage.jsp">value2</a>

          value3<input type="number" min="1" name="value3">
         <a href="somePage.jsp">value3</a>
```

I have three input text associated with three hyper link and if I hit any link then value in respective text-box should appended to URL and we go to next page.
In this case **somePage.jsp?Value=2** something like this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the content of the href attribute via JavaScript, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript).

Comment: Yes,André but I am not going to click any button...

Comment: You can change the href of the respective link when the link is clicked?

Comment: I have tried that too but only name is get appende not value just like "somePage.jsp?value=" and when I debuged I foud that value is undefined...

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<a id="reflectedlink" href="http://www.google.com/search">http://www.google.com/search</a>
```

I will show you with an example, here on keyup event i am dynamically changing href value.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link= document.getElementById('reflectedlink');
    var input= document.getElementById('searchterm');
input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
    link.search= '?q='+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
    link.firstChild.data= link.href;
};
```

Check the same in https://jsfiddle.net/aadi/pr5j9Lbv/

Comment: If this solved your problem, please don't forgot to upvote and mark it as solved.
This will help others looking for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

thanks André I have got my mistake. the problem is solved by your [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript), But I have made mistake is I am given same name for all the links....