# How to avoid redirecting the click on href but need to change the url in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have table data(td) as hyperlink(href). If i click the td then its redirect. Now i want to change the URL only not the redirection.I use the following code:

```
 <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/" .$Users->UserPcKey; ?>">
<?php echo $Users->UserPcKey; ?></a></td>
```

Thanks .

Comment: Do you mean change element on click? Mind using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the preventDefault function like this in JQuery, it will be more in front code than in back code for the behaviour you expect.
Here the link I disable is the one with the id "myLink" :

```
<script>
    $('#myLink').click(function(e)
        $(this).attr("href","http://your_link.com");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... at the mean time , what is mylink? And chay i want to change url in onclick of href. ...And also i have n number of <td>'s in my code.

Comment: I am asking while click on the href it automatically redirect. But in my code,        i need the url change but not redirection. If i use above code the url change is not done. So guide me.

Comment: I just edited, I think this will be good if you want just to update the url after the clic

Answer (score 0):

**If prevent default is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.**

```
$(function(){
    $("#anchorId").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr("href","http://newlink.com");
    }); });​​​​
```

Comment: If i use the prevent default(), then the url is not change by href. In my above code i change the id in url but dont need redirection.

Comment: prevent default() will replace your base URL, change it to newlink.com so when you click on td it will redirect to newlink.com not your base url. i hope this is what you want...

Comment: In my code the new link url changes based on the row value on each click. So how can i pre-define?