# Determine which link (on same page) was used?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, url, seo

I have a page with two links to an introduction/registration page. We want to show different content based on which link the user uses. They appear in different contexts on the same page, and we would like to tailor the message on the registration page to that context. For SEO purposes I was told not to change the URL.

I'm using rails. Since the incoming user will have the same referrer regardless of which link was clicked, what is the best way to know which link was used to get to my page? Is it possible in a practical way without altering the URL?

Comment: Both links have the same href?

Comment: Yes. Both would be like example.com/register but appearing in different parts of the page.

Comment: can you post some codes which best describes your scenario?

Comment: add different params in links

Answer (score 0):

I would change the href on click like described in [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

But I would not change the whole url. I would only append a parameter. This should not influence SEO.