# Change href by finding id- javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, getelementbyid

I am very new to JS and a Swift developer. I have a button that has this  property:

```
<a href="http://phonefiveme.com/nocontact" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1490136681073_127" style="cursor: url(&quot;chrome-extension://ledmjlnkdlappilhaaihfhanlpdjjalm/rockhand.png&quot;), auto;">
```

What I need to do is to edit that href to be a link that is stored in a variable. Here is what I have:

```
    var currentLocation = window.location;
    var stringURL = String(currentLocation);
    var shortened = stringURL.substring(32);
    var myElement = document.getElementById("yui_3_17_2_1_1490136681073_127");
```

I just need to replace "http://phonefiveme.com/nocontact" with `shortened`

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks so much. 
Cheers,
Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [href](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_href.asp) JavaScript property.

Simply add to your JavaScript:

```
myElement.href = shortened;
```

See [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript) question for more reference.

Comment: does the question above yours work as well? i will mark both correct if they both do

Comment: @TheoStrauss both will work in the same manner. However the other answer is doing a String replace. The String replace method relies on the href initially staying as "http://phonefiveme.com/nocontact" otherwise it will not be able to replace the String correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
var stringURL = String(currentLocation);
var shortened = stringURL.substring(32);
var myElement = document.getElementById("yui_3_17_2_1_1490136681073_127");
myElement.href = myElement.href.replace("http://phonefiveme.com/nocontact", shortened);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the properties of the html element and simply use

```
myElement.href=shortened;
```

to do the trick