# Javascript: Forcing All Links to Goto Same URL?

Tags: javascript

i have many different links on the page and instead of changing them one by one, i want to force them all to goto the same URL using Javascript (or php if possible)

Is there a way I can define where I want all URLs to go at the top of the page? so when a user clicks any link it will goto  the URL specified in javascript?

Comment: Dup? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript

Comment: No, not really.  Not without a really hacky approach.  Are all the links internal or are some external?

Comment: @JosephMarikle the links im replacing are internal, the 1 that i will replace with will be external

Comment: Only way I can think of doing this is looping through all `<a>` tags and changing the `href` value, but I don't know.. doesn't feel like good practice.

Comment: Something that would be even more sneaky is to attach a click event to all <a> tags, prevent the default event action, and redirect the to the desired webpage. This way, all of the links would look like they're going somewhere else, but you are interrupting the flow to insert your own URL... Sneaky, right?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
const links=document.links;
Array.from(links).map((a)=>a.setAttribute("href","https://google.com"));
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
```

seams that _blank is not working on SO but trust me: [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/NightKn8/ruwsLc51/)
**Edit:**
Since you may wish to spare anchors on your page starting with `#` you can add the following `if`:

```js
const links=document.links;
Array.from(links).map((a)=> (!a.getAttribute('href').match(/^\#.*/m)) ? a.setAttribute("href","https://google.com") : false);
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">SO</a>
<a href="#C4">Chapter 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can Use jquery`
$('a').attr('href','your url');
//Or JAVASCRIPT
n=getElementsByTagName('a').length
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i].setAttribute("href", "your URL");
}
```