# Javascript set href for all elements in class

Tags: javascript

I have a list of (at least 4) < a > tags with the class 'remove-typefilter'
They do not have a 'href' ., but I want to give them all one when the users clicks a button.

This is the JS function I've written to achieve this:

```
function BuildButtons(urlparams) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-typefilter')
    for (let element in elements) {
        element.href = 'www.newlink.com' + urlparams
        element.style = 'color: red;'
    }
}
```

Yet when I run this function it does not change the attributs. The A tags get no link and the styling goes not change.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

- Syntax error in the function definition: `url-params` is invalid. Use `urlParams`.
- `for ... in` loops iterate the keys of the iterated object, not the values. Use `for ... of` instead

Also:

- Do not define `elements` as a global variable. Use `const`.
- Better add a protocol in your URL, like `http://`
- Although assigning a string to `style` works, it is more efficient to assign directly to the relevant style property

Corrected code:

```
function BuildButtons(urlParams) {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-typefilter');
    for (const element of elements) {
        element.href = 'http://www.newlink.com' + urlParams;
        element.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set the href attribute by using the

```
Element.setAttribute(*name*,*value*);
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops return the index not the actual element.

```
for (let element in elements) {
```

should be

```
for (let i in elements) {
    let element = elements[i];
```

or

```
elements.forEach(function(element) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function BuildButtons(urlparams) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.remove-typefilter'); 
    elements.forEach(function(element){
        element.href = 'www.newlink.com' + urlparams
        element.style = 'color: red;'
    });
};

BuildButtons('#xxx');  // invoke call the function how ever you like.
```

```html
<a class="remove-typefilter">one</a>
<a class="remove-typefilter">two</a>
<a class="remove-typefilter">three</a>
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks!

Comment: In my opinion there were other answers given before this one, that also *explained* what was wrong.

Comment: @Jasper https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423517/295783 is the more complete answer.

Comment: @Jasper I agree with mplungjan and trincot. `trincot`s answer should be the accepted one and not mine. His answer explains what you were doing wrong + why and how you can fix. My answer is just another approach on how you can solve the task you have.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I've set trincots answer as the accepted one.