# Change href through css

Tags: css, wordpress, button, href, multilingual

Is it possible to change the href of a button through css only?

I have a multilingual wordpress website, and am trying to adapt the home page of my theme to a second language. I have figured out how to change the text of the welcome headers and buttons, however, I would like the translated buttons to link to the translated pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with CSS. Here's a solution to doing something similar in JavaScript. [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I think I can only edit the css.