# Put http:// on hrefs missing a protocol in Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have been trying to figure out a solution to replace all hrefs that do not have *http://* or *https://* in front of a link with an appended version of the link with http:// on it.

Currently I have something like this:

```
static correctUrls(input: string): string {

  // get all hrefs from the input
  let urls = input.match('<a[^>]* href="([^"]*)"/g');

  // if no urls return original input
  if (!urls) {
    return input;
  }

  // remove duplicate urls
  urls = urls.filter((item, pos) => {
    return urls.indexOf(item) === pos;
  });

  // if no urls in input
  if (!urls) {
    return input;
  }

  for (const url of urls) {

    // if url does not have https
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    if (!url.match('^ (http: \/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$')) {
      input = input.replace(url, 'https://' + url);
    }
  }
  return input;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please include an explanation of how your answer's regex works. I have found lots of similar questions to this one, but with all of the solutions I have found, when I try to do `input.match` it returns the matched `href` twice (if there is one), but if there are two `href`s then it returns rubbish.

Here is the input:

```html
<p> We love
  <a href="https://google.com"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     target="_blank">Google</a>
  and
  <a href="Facebook.com"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     target="_blank">Facebook</a>.
</p>
```

And the expected output:

```html
<p> We love
  <a href="https://google.com"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     target="_blank">Google</a>
  and
  <a href="https://Facebook.com"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     target="_blank">Facebook</a>.
</p>
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse out HTML.  Use the DOM to find the anchor tags and their `href` attributes and the `URL` class to parse them.

Comment: I'm using Angular, gonna try creating a new HtmlElement() and setting the .innerHtml to the input and navigating the DOM that way.

Comment: If you have the HTML as a string, you can parse it using the DOM without actually adding it to the page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser instead.

Comment: @Amy Thank you that's what helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this in Angular is to use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). Then you can select all elements with the anchor  tag. Then you can apply the regex to see if it has either http or https in front of it.

```
export class UrlCorrector {
  static correctUrls(input: string): string {

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const document = parser.parseFromString(input, 'text/html');

    // get all anchor tags from the input
    const anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // if no anchor tags return original input
    if (anchorTags.length === 0) {
      return input;
    }

    const urls: string[] = [];

    // iterate through all the anchor tags to find their urls
    // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < anchorTags.length; i++) {

      const href = anchorTags[i].href;
      let url = href;

      // if url has hostname in it, it's a href without http protocol
      if (href.includes(location.hostname)) {

        // get just the ending part e.g., `localhost:4200/submissions/facebook.com` will return `facebook.com`
        url = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      }
      urls.push(url);
    }

    for (const url of urls) {

      // if url does not have a protocol append https:// to front
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      if (!url.match('^ (http: \/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$')) {
        input = input.replace(url, 'https://' + url);
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex is the wrong too for the job.** You're already in javascript - it's got an abundance of tools for DOM management, many of which do [exactly what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365272/7431860). Please, try to use these instead, they're much more applicable to your task!

If you *really* want to do it with regex, `href="(?!https?:\/\/)()[^"]+"` should do the job.

- `href="` Look for `href="` string to start the match
- `(?!https?:\/\/)` Assert there's no `http://` or `https://` at the start of the URL
- `()` Empty capture at the start of the URL you want to edit - insert your string here
- `[^"]+"` Match content up to the next quote mark; this is the rest of the URL

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNpSm9/2/)

A sample Javascript program using this method:

```
var x = '<p> We love <a href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Google</a> and <a href="Facebook.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Facebook</a>. <a href="www.example.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Facebook</a>. <a href="http://www.example.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Facebook</a>. </p>'
var urls = x.match('href="(?!https?:\/\/)()([^"]+)"')

console.log("https://" + urls[2])
```

`'https://Facebook.com'`

Comment: Using expected input and .match result was ["href="Facebook.com"", ""]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: But I am going to use the DOM instead.

Comment: Sounds good. Please be sure to accept the answer if it addresses your question, OR flag a moderator to close the question (without deleting) so future users can reference it.

Comment: Using chrome I get the following value for urls when executing your Javascript code:  ["href="Facebook.com", "", "Facebook.com"]

Comment: That's expected behavior - you can get just "Facebook.com" with `urls[2]`, since `urls` is an array returned by `x.match()`. You can also remove the empty capture group and reference `urls[1]` instead if you would like.

Comment: Is it possible for the first regex to return ['https://google.com', 'Facebook.com'], simply just getting the hrefs? Then I was planning on using a second regex to determine if it had a protocol in front of it or not.

Comment: That's more complicated, and again, better suited to a DOM parser. Please consider using code similar to the link in the answer.

Comment: Sorry then this is not an answer