# Make Anchor tag work conditionally using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Radio button. I want to implement a validation on "Submit" Anchor tag that displays an error if no selection is made on the radio button and redirects to the URL provided in the `href` attribute if the radio button selection is made.

Below is the code for radio button -

```
<div>
    <input required="" type="radio" id="group02-0" name="group02" value="Yes" onclick="yesnoCheck();">
    <label for="group02-0" >Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="group02-1" name="group02" value="No" onclick="yesnoCheck();">
    <label for="group02-1">No</label>
</div>

<script>
    var radio_value = "";
    function yesnoCheck() {
        radio_value = document.querySelector('input[name="group02"]:checked').value;
    }
</script>
```

In the same `HTML` file, I have code for the Submit Anchor tag -

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="return submitCheck();"><span>Submit</span></a>

<script>
    function submitCheck() {
        if (radio_value === "") {
            //Display an error. The user should not be taken to the next page
            return false;
        } else {
            //User should be taken to the URL in the href attribute
            return true;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Irrespective of whether I make a selection on the radio button, the anchor tag always takes me to the next page. Please help!

Comment: One radio is required?  What? Why? Just make one of them `checked` by default...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365272/2777098

Comment: Your code works well on my Chrome browser.

Comment: I checked your code on a live server, when no radio is selected, anchor tag does not take me to the next page. Where are you running the code?

Comment: FYI all you need is a single `[ ] YES` **checkbox**. It's a better UI and UX than having two radio buttons - which are both obscurely unchecked....

Comment: @PJohnson Im using chrome as well.

Comment: I'm using chrome too, is it possible the value is kept even if you leave the page? I have no idea if this has anything to do with it, but maybe try to run incognito, maybe an extension or something is the issue?

Comment: @PJohnson - YES! That was the problem. The value was not being refreshed. You saved the day!

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: see my answer below, don't miss the use of css  **pointer-events: none;**

Answer (score 2):

- You don't need two radio buttons. Only one Checkbox.
- Use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent default browser navigation
- Use the input element's `checked` state to determine the outcome
- Finally use `document.location` to navigate to a  `EL_submitBtn.getAttribute('href')`
- PS: Don't use inline JavaScript (in HTML). JS should be in one place and that's your JS file or inside a `<script>` tag. It's easier to debug and maintain.

## Single checkbox

```js
const EL_submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');
const EL_acceptCkb = document.querySelector('[name="accept"]'); 

function submitCheck(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent follow link
  
  if (!EL_acceptCkb.checked) {              // Unchecked
    alert("You will not get a better UX");
  } else {                                  // Checked
    alert("Yes! Buckle up!")
    document.location = EL_submitBtn.getAttribute('href');  
  }
}

EL_submitBtn.addEventListener('click', submitCheck);
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Would you like a better UX?</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accept"> Yes I do
  </label>
</div>

<a id="submitBtn" href="https://www.google.com">Submit</a>
```

## Two radio buttons

- Use `document.querySelector('[name="accept"]:checked')` to get the checked one, if any.

```js
const EL_submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');

function submitCheck(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent follow link
  
  const EL_acceptCkd = document.querySelector('[name="accept"]:checked'); 
  
  if (!EL_acceptCkd) {                      // None checked
    alert("You must select Yes or No.");
  } else if (EL_acceptCkd.value === 'no') { // "NO" checked
    alert("You will not get a better UX");
  } else {                                  // "YES" checked
    alert("Yes! Buckle up!")
    document.location = EL_submitBtn.getAttribute('href');
  }
}

EL_submitBtn.addEventListener('click', submitCheck);
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Would you like a better UX?</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="accept" value="yes"> Yes
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="accept" value="no"> No
  </label>
</div>

<a id="submitBtn" href="https://www.google.com">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Having a radio button is a requirement. Cant use checkbox

Comment: @ArchitArora added an example with the two radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

use css  **pointer-events: none;** -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

If you absolutely want to use button radios (even if it's a bit twisted as an idea) here is the code:

```js
const aHrefGoogle = document.getElementById('aHrefGoogle');

document.querySelectorAll('input[name=group02]').forEach(el=>
  {
  el.onchange=_=>{ if (el.checked) setLinkOnOff(el.value) }
  })

function setLinkOnOff(val)
  {
  if (val==='yes') { aHrefGoogle.classList.remove('adisableHref') }
  else             { aHrefGoogle.classList.add('adisableHref')    }
  }
```

```css
.adisableHref {
  color: grey; 
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

```html
make link Google active ?
<label ><input type="radio" name="group02" value="yes">Yes </label>&nbsp;
<label ><input type="radio" name="group02" value="no" checked>No! </label>

<br><br>

<a href="https://www.google.com"  id="aHrefGoogle" class="adisableHref"><span> Google </span></a>
```

for memo here is the initial code with a checkbox :

```js
const yesnoCheck  = document.getElementById('yesnoCheck')
  ,   aHrefGoogle = document.getElementById('aHrefGoogle')
  ;

// init
yesnoCheck.checked = false
aHrefGoogle.classList.add('adisableHref') 

yesnoCheck.oninput =_=>
  {
  if (yesnoCheck.checked)  { aHrefGoogle.classList.remove('adisableHref')    }
  else                     { aHrefGoogle.classList.add('adisableHref') }
  }
```

```css
#yesnoCheck  { display: none; }
#yesnoCheck + label { display: inline-block; background: #cd3c3c; color: white; padding: .17em .2em; cursor: pointer; }
#yesnoCheck:checked + label { background: #378b2c; }
#yesnoCheck + label::before { content: 'NO'; display: inline-block; width:2.6em; text-align: center; }
#yesnoCheck + label::after  { content: '';   display: inline-block; width:0;     text-align: center; }
#yesnoCheck:checked + label::before { content: '';    width:0; }
#yesnoCheck:checked + label::after  { content: 'YES'; width:2.6em; }

.adisableHref {
  color: grey;
  pointer-events: none;  
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration-line: none;
}
```

```html
make link Google active ?
<input type="checkbox" id="yesnoCheck"><label for="yesnoCheck">▉</label>

<br><br>

<a href="https://www.google.com"  id="aHrefGoogle" class="adisableHref"><span> Google </span></a>
```