# Javascript var in href tag

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I would like to put a dynamic link in a href tag with window.location.href

How can I do this?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url="+ <script> window.location.href </script>+ "&text=!" target="_blank">
  Twitter
</a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change href of <a> tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could give the `a` an id and look it up by that.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('href', `https://twitter.com/share?url="${window.location.href}&text=!`);
```

```html
<a id="foo" target="_blank">
  Twitter
</a>
```

Comment: It's a duplicate, I think that it should be marked as such rather than answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('a');
el.href = el.href+window.location.href + '&text=!';
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=" target="_blank">
  Twitter
</a>
```