# Is it possible to use CSS to change a Link in a button in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the link on an existing button in Wordpress to another page with CSS. Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="https://site1.com/" class="MyButton">Site</a>
```

site1.com to site2.com.. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with CSS. instead, you can do it with JavaScript. Here's a solution to do something similar in JavaScript.
[How to change href of  tag on button click through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript)