# Unable to use the response gathered by Fetch API and use it in my code later

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a HTML, CSS, JS website and want to incorporate an API and use the response further in my website.

I've managed to make this API part work but I'm stuck with the final part.

- What I've Achieved

  1. Executing a JS function using FETCH that makes a POST Call with Auth Headers
  2. Getting the response to show up inside my Chrome Developer Console.
- What I'm trying to achieve

  1. Use the Response (Web URL) that is being received by the POST API Call inside my
     website as a variable. So when the user hits a button this response (URL) opens up in
     a new tab.

In simple terms, I want the make use of the web url that shows up in the Chrome Console.

Here is the code I'm using

```
  function initiateIDV(){

  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  
  var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "customerInternalReference": "Will's App",
    },
    "userReference": "test-app",
    "tokenLifetime": "10m"
  });
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  
  fetch("https://[hidden]/api/v1/accounts", requestOptions)

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result.web.href))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));   
   
}
```

[View From the Chrome Console of a Successful Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY8pp.png)

Comment: What do you mean by “make use of the web url”? how do you wanna make use of the data?

Comment: are you closing your curly bracket too early in your `raw` object?

Comment: Are you asking about the bindings?  you just want to access the physical URL of the API?

Comment: @seriously, So the Response has a lot of Data like Timestamp, Account ID, Web URL etc. in it. And I'm looking to make use of the Web URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 things to check first before make sure the value show in the Console.

1. **Network request**. Check in the Network panel to see if the network request call successful? If it's not fix the url or the API. Learn [inspect network request](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/)
2. **Log the result**. Log the `result` object first to see if it contains `.web.href`. If it's not, fix the API.

I create a working example from your code. Run it and you will see result. I changed the API url to a demo url

```js
function initiateIDV(){

  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  
  // changed body content
  var raw = JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
  })
  
  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  // changed url
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));   
}

initiateIDV();
```

Comment: As I've mentioned originally in my question. I'm successfully able to get the response to show up in my Chrome Console.

Answer (score 0):

Let me paraphrase your question. You want to:

1. make a POST request to an API
2. handle the API response in your JavaScript code
3. open a new tab in the user's browser, at the URL contained in the API response

And you are stuck at step 3.

What you are trying to achieve at step 3 is an **effect** (aka a **side effect**) on the user's browser.

Also, a minor remark about the terminology you used:

> So when the user hits a button this response (URL) opens up in a new tab.

In your example the response is not a URL. You are calling `response.json()`, so the API response is JSON.

You are already performing a side effect at step 3: `console.log()`. A lot of stuff is a side effect. Basically everything that changes some kind of **state**. Printing something in the browser's console, showing an alert dialog, adding/removing CSS classes, adding/removing/altering DOM elements, are all side effects.

The side effect you want to achieve here is to open a new tab in the user's browser. In JS you can do it using this code:

```
window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/", '_blank').focus()
```

The **state** in your scenario is the fact that the browser currently has N tabs open, and after `window.open()` will have N+1 tabs open. And not only that. Opening a tab in Chrome might spawn a new operating system process (before the relationship was 1 tab => 1 process, but nowadays I don't think so, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1525313/force-chrome-to-open-each-tab-in-its-own-process)).

Comment: you are right with your paraphrase. And I am stuck at 3.

Comment: window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/", '_blank').focus()

Does open up in a new browser I get that, 

But I want the Web URL that returns in the API Response to be able to be part of a button in my webpage. So From your example, I want the https://stackoverflow.com/ to be replaced by the Web URL from the API Response.

Comment: `window.open` opens a new browser **tab**. Opening a new **browser** would mean that you open a new Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. Try to edit your question. It's not that clear. If you need to replace the **text** in the `<button>` with the URL from the API, you need to select the button, for example with `document.querySelector('#your-button')`, and change its text. Instead, if you need to open a new tab when the user **clicks** that button, you need to attach and event listener to that button, and call `window.open` inside that listener.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you. So I am not trying to change the text of the button. I want the response URL from the API to be the Href of this button. So when clicked it takes the user to that Response URL (In a new tab)

Comment: then your task is basically the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript

Comment: I can't see them using fetch or any API Calls in that task. In my case, the response of the API (WEB URL) should be the href of the Button.